# Basic query using "WITH" results in "Unrecognized name" error

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, with-statement

I know this is a very basic question, I'm just learning SQL, so sorry if I'm missing something obvious.

When I run the below query I get an error:

> Unrecognized name: avg_price at [12:15]

```
WITH avg_price AS
(
    SELECT 
        AVG(UnitPrice)
    FROM 
        `erics-test-data-project.sales.sales` 
)
SELECT 
    UnitPrice
FROM 
    `erics-test-data-project.sales.sales`
WHERE
    UnitPrice > avg_price
```

I thought I defined `avg_price` in line 1 (following the basic `WITH` syntax from BigQuery documentation. I tried enabling legacy SQL dialect but that gave me another error:

> Encountered " "WITH" "WITH "" at line 1, column 1. Was expecting:  [Try using standard SQL (https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/enabling-standard-sql)]

Comment: Can you share your table definition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
WITH avg_price AS(
  SELECT 
    AVG(UnitPrice) as avg_UnitPrice
  FROM 
    `erics-test-data-project.sales.sales`
)
SELECT 
  UnitPrice
FROM 
  `erics-test-data-project.sales.sales`, avg_price
WHERE
  UnitPrice > avg_UnitPrice
```

Answer (score 0):

### You have missed alias name for AVG(UnitPrice) aslo not used avg_price properly in last query.

### Try this:-

```
WITH avg_price AS
   (SELECT 
     AVG(UnitPrice) AVG_UnitPrice
   FROM 
     `erics-test-data-project.sales.sales` 
   )
 SELECT 
   UnitPrice
 FROM 
   `erics-test-data-project.sales.sales`
    cross join avg_price
 WHERE
   UnitPrice > AVG_UnitPrice
```

Answer (score 0):

The avg_price should be treated similarly to a view or a temporary table. What you can do is update the where clause to select the average price value from the common table expression.

```
WHERE UnitPrice > (SELECT * FROM avg_price)
```

You could also take a different approach and simplify your whole query using an analytic function.

```
SELECT 
  UnitPrice
FROM 
  `erics-test-data-project.sales.sales`
QUALIFY
  UnitPrice > AVG(UnitPrice) OVER()
```